# WiringPi and Flask Sudo Conflict

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, virtualenv, wiringpi

I am running my application in a virtualenv using Python3.4.

WiringPi requires sudo privilege to access the hardware pins. Flask, on the other hand, resides in my virtualEnv folder, so I can't access it using `sudo flask`.

I've tried making it run on startup by placing some commands in `/etc/rc.local` so that it can have root access automatically. It only tells me that it can't find basic Python library modules (like `re`).

My RPI2 is running Raspbian. For the time being I am running it using `flask run --localhost=0.0.0.0`, which I know I am not supposed to do, but I'll change that later.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had to make sure that "root" had the proper libraries installed too. Root and User have different directories for their Python binaries.